# The derivative of square root of $g$ from numerical values of $g$ and $g'$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to do this:

> Function $g(x) > 0$, $g(1) = 9$, $g'(1) = 4$. If $h(x) = (g(x))^{1/2}$, 
>   find $h'(1)$

I got $2/3$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If $h(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}$, what we should do is apply the chain rule for derivatives.

It follows that $h'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}$. Now let x=1, so

$h'(1)=\frac{g'(1)}{2\sqrt{g(1)}}=\frac{4}{2\sqrt9}=\frac{4}{2*3}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$

So it indeed appears that you are correct.

Comment: For  David Yu: You should probably show how you got your answer, for future reference. Note that Sherlock showed his work--you should do that as a courtesy so he doesn't have to show what you didn't.